# Copying file contents to clipboard and pasting into a plain text file automatically in python

Tags: python, python-3.5

All I am trying to accomplish with this little script that I wrote is to parse data from a PDF file.

However, I seem to have run into an issue with python, more specifically the PyPDF2 module not able to read the text from a pdf file. The data printed out is all fuzzy and basically not readable. However, when I open up the pdf file that I am trying to read I can simply `click drag and ctrl+c` to copy contents after which when I paste it into a plain txt document it works flawlessly. The data is readable when I go through this process of copying and pasting manually.

So what I'm trying to do is mimic that exact step, however automate it instead of having me go through all the pages within the pdf file performing the above steps.

Or if there are any suggestion as to what else I can do to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate it. I have tried converting the pdf file into a docx and plain text files however the contents of the file had their formats completely re arranged

```
import PyPDF2
pdfFileObj = open('sjsuclassdata.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pdfReader.numPages

pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(4)
print(pageObj.extractText())
```

**EDIT**
Essentially what Im trying to do now is to simply write a script that would perform the following actions.

1.) Read pdf file

2.) copy contents of whole page (ctrl+a)

3.) paste contents of whole page into plain text file (ctrl+v)

4.) read pdf till end of file

Answer (score 0):

I would give slate a try:

```
import slate

output_prefix = 'foobar'
file_ext = 'txt'

with open('example.pdf') as f:
        doc = slate.PDF(f)
        for page_number, page in enumerate(doc):
            open('%s_%s.%s' % (output_suffix, page_number, file_ext), 'w+').write(doc[page_number])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however, I've been trying to install slate to no avail :(